# How to merge the name of the canvas which is being obtained from an input field with the canvas in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Initially I was merging the canvas and the name var i want to assign to it (where name is being obtained from an input field)when downloading the canvas.
But I don't want to download the canvas , instead I want to merge the canvas and its name and convert it into image data(base 64) and then move it to the server where I will decode it into image .

How do i merge The 2 variables and then convert it into image data using DataURL?

Js code:

```
  var name = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenField1").val();

  var mergeCanvas = $('<canvas>')
        .attr({
            width: $(img).width(),
            height: $(img).height()
        });

  var mergedContext = mergeCanvas[0].getContext('2d');
  mergedContext.clearRect(0, 0, $(img).width(), $(img).height());
  mergedContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  mergedContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

  This.downloadCanvas(mergeCanvas[0], name);
```

Comment: What do you call *merging* here? You want to draw it as text on the resulting image? Then [fillText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText) is your friend. You just want to have a binary file which filename would be set to `name` on your server? Then send that name along with the image's data and set that to the filename from your server (or use [`formData.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)`(canvas_as_blob, 'field', 'filename.png')`)

Comment: I mean to save the particular canvas by the name in the name var.

Comment: @Kaiido , does this make sense? need help refining this:           var Img = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
 Img = Img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")

 var fileName =  $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenField1").val();
 var file = new File(Img, fileName);

 var fd = new FormData();
 formData.append(Img_as_blob, file, 'fileName.png');

Comment: Instead of `canvas.toDataURL()`, use directly `canvas.toBlob(function(canvas_as_blob) { fd.append(...`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to give the user the option to specify a filename in an input field and then download the canvas content with the given filename?

In that case, you can create a link element with the data URL of the canvas as the "href" attribute and the filename as the "download" attribute.

Let's say your HTML looks roughly like this:

```
<p>
  <label>
    File name: <input id="filename">
    <button id="save">Download</button>
  </label>
</p>
<canvas width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

then you can do the following in your JavaScript:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
document.querySelector('#save').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var filename = document.querySelector('#filename').value
  var downloadLink = document.createElement('a')
  downloadLink.setAttribute('href', canvas.toDataURL())
  downloadLink.setAttribute('download', filename)
  downloadLink.click();
})
```

[Here is a working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/avgp/re8v4b2u/2/)

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I do not want to download the canvas ..I just want to convert the canvas into image data and then move that to the server and name the canvas from the name var when i decode the binary file.      var Img = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
 Img = Img.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "")

 var fileName =  $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenField1").val();
 var file = new File(Img, fileName);

 var fd = new FormData();
 formData.append(Img_as_blob, file, 'fileName.png');

Comment: If that makes sense..though thats not correct i guess..need help refining that.